windows is not getting detected in boot menu
I had dual boot in my PC (Windows and Ubuntu). I wanted to change GUI of boot menu so I downloaded rEFInd in ubuntu to make the boot menu look better. Previous structure- boot/efi/EFI/ I mistakenly moved EFI outside in boot/ directory boot |-efi |-EFI and rebooted my PC. It showed neither Windows nor Ubuntu in boot menu. Asked me to insert external bootable device. I had Ubuntu in my USB so, when I started with that USB Drive, it had all the memory as before for both windows as well ubuntu. Then, I thought of reinstalling ubuntu in the same location as before. It installed succcessfully and to my surprise now it is opening but windows is not available in boot menu. I tried to access it through Ubuntu Files, it showed me this error (screenshot attached) -> Unable to access location I am able to access other windows drive but not C: Drive. Kindly help me regaining my windows back, its important for me to regain access as it has important stuffs in it.
